# PHP login script error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a script for login system for my project. I thought I am correct in coding this, but it gives me problem. And the problem is that it does not allow to log me in and redirects to `login.php` page. Below is the code;

```
<?php
include('./include/connection.php');
$tabName = "adminuser";
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(empty($userName)){
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
}
$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($userName);
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($password));

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $tabName WHERE userName = '".$userName."' 
             AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";
$sqlExe = mysql_query($sqlQuery);

$count = mysql_num_rows($sqlExe);

if($count > 0){
    header('location: index.php');
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
}else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password <br />".
    '<a href="login.php">Go back...</a>';
}
?>
```

Here is seesion code on `"index.php"` page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']) or $_SESSION['auth'] != 1){
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Please correct me and let me know where im wrong. And please also tell me that, Is my code is sql injection safe?

Comment: This calls for basic step-by-step debugging, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Hmmm yeah this is definitely going to work: `$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($password))`. Copy/paste programming?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($userName) || ){
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Remove the or `||` in the if statement.

That should be a parse error in the first place. I'm not sure why it is even redirecting.

As for SQL injection, it has been discussed multiple times see : [this](http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=prevent%20sql%20stackoverflow)

Comment: As pakka said this calls for basic step-by-step debugging, not a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you have to exit a `header()`.
For example:

```
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
```

and put that after the `$_SESSION['auth'] = 1` statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. - '".$var."' try changing it to '.$var.' in the query
2. - try setting the session BEFORE the header..

I'm no guru or anything, but i know php sometimes fail on small insignificant things